# iOS Webapp Cache Manifest for Video files

Tags: ios, caching, web-applications, manifest

I made a WebApp for an iPad which is supposed to run in an intranet. The app is basically a form, kind of an exam. Some questions has videos (videos are around 20MB size). I've defined my cache manifest as follow:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
```

CACHE:
/videos/preg1Calidad.m4v
/videos/preg2Calidad.m4v

The .manifest file content-type header is "text/cache-manifest". The thing is that, as this webapp is supposed to access some webservices to read/write data on a database located in a server connected to the intranet, I need the iPads to be connected to the network. When I add my app to the home screen and a question containing a video is prompted, I can see the video is being fetched from the network (I can see the loading animation next to the WiFi icon) istead of being accessed from the iPad itself.

I've deleted safari's data storage, cache, historial, deleted the app and added again, nothing seems to work. The content-type for the .m4v video I've setted it up to "video/mp4".

So, I've several questions:

- How can I know for sure if the files on the .manifest are being cached?
- I know some browsers apparently has a maximum size of storage for offline apps, never the less, looking into the apple documentation I haven't seen such a thing. Is there any limitation with iPads on file size? Maybe file types?
- I don't know if I'm miss understanding the behavior of the webapp for offline access, the definition of the .manifest file, I've been thinking that it might only work when the device is actually offline (no network connection available, airplane mode maybe) but I thought that defining a file as "CACHE" would do the trick so this file wouldn't be accessed from the network. Shouldn't it behave like that?

I can not start developing this as native app at the moment since its kind in production. If anyone gets an idea on how to fix it quickly, would be great. I've been thinking on add the files to the internal database as base64 or in a javascript varial (as base64 also).

Thanks so much.